# Code to retrieve GeoJSON data not working

Tags: android, geojson

I am trying to retrieve `GeoJSON` data to display it in a custom `listview`  for my earthquake alert app but the app shuts down unexpectedly. Here's my code:

**CODE**

```
public class JSONActivity extends ListActivity {    
ListAdapter adapter;
String data;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ListView listview;

private static final String TAG_FEATURES= "features";
private static final String TAG_PROPERTIES= "properties";
private static final String TAG_MAG= "mag";
private static final String TAG_PLACE= "place";
private static final String TAG_TIME= "time";
private static final String TAG_TYPE= "type";

JSONArray features = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> EarthquakeList;

public String readJSONFeed(String URL){     

    StringBuilder stringBuilder=  new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
    try{

        HttpResponse response= client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine= response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if(statusCode == 200){

            HttpEntity entity= response.getEntity();
            data= EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while((line= reader.readLine())!= null)
            {

                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }

        }else{
            Log.e("JSON", "Failed to download file");
        }

    }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();

}

private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

//  @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(JSONActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show(); 
    }       

protected void onPostExecute(String result){

    if (pDialog.isShowing())
         pDialog.dismiss();
    try{            

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
         features = jsonObj.getJSONArray("features");
         for (int i = 0; i < features.length(); i++) 
         {

            JSONObject c = features.getJSONObject(i);

               // Properties node is JSON Object
             JSONObject properties = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PROPERTIES);
             String mag = properties.getString(TAG_MAG);
             String place = properties.getString(TAG_PLACE);
             String type = properties.getString(TAG_TYPE);
             String time  = properties.getString(TAG_TIME);

                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),mag,3000).show();
             // tmp hash map for single contact
             HashMap<String, String> earthquake = new HashMap<String, String>();

             // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
             earthquake.put(TAG_MAG, mag);
             earthquake.put(TAG_PLACE, place);
             earthquake.put(TAG_TYPE, type);
             earthquake.put(TAG_TIME,time);

             EarthquakeList.add(earthquake);

            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */


            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    JSONActivity.this , EarthquakeList ,
                            R.layout.list_item , new String[] { TAG_MAG, TAG_PLACE,
                                    TAG_TIME,TAG_TYPE }, new int[] { R.id.mag,
                                    R.id.place, R.id.time,R.id.type });
            setListAdapter(adapter);               
         }          
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }               
}   

}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    listview= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    EarthquakeList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();       

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }});
    new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson");

}
}
```

This is main.xml

**CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

this is list_item.xml
**CODE**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mag"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="#43bd00"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/place"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="#43bd00"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:text="Place : " />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
     android:text="Time: "
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="#acacac" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Type: "
    android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**logcat**

```
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.JSON/com.JSON.JSONActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at ``android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:245)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.JSON.JSONActivity.onCreate(JSONActivity.java:187)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-19 12:30:49.302: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you add your `log cat`?

Comment: Please add you stack trace and provide further information..

Answer (score 0):

Did you include .geojson into your MIME types to be resolved on your web server?

If not, you might need to edit web.config to resolve your geoJSON mime type under your webServer section by

```
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".geojson" mimeType="application/json" />
```